# jQuery datepicker markup customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How can I pull this off?  I want to utilize what jQuery UI offers here without rewriting my own calendar.

I need to be able to customize the layout (physical table layout).  I need to actually CHANGE the way the calendar is presented (not style wise).

I need some way to implement the decorator pattern on the datepicker.

I tried to inject using .insertAfter, but that did not seem to work well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pretty much stuck with the default functionality from the jquery calandar.
It is however very modifiable so i would certainly advice you to check out all the options.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

If the default jquery ui calendar doesn't fit your need then there are a lot of customizable  third party calendars as well, easy to hit up with google, here are a phew all ready:

http://www.queness.com/post/656/10-beautiful-jquery-and-mootool-calendar-plugins

You can if you really want to inject and modify objects inside the generated code but i certainly wouldn't advice this, you can't know if your code will keep working if jQuery upgrades and it will not be trivial, you would probably be better of writing your own widget then.

Comment: I've added more info to question, I think you are misunderstanding.

Comment: @dbobrowski I think he is misunderstanding because you are being extremely vague in what you are actually try to accomplish. Why dont you give us an example so we can actually help you.

Comment: @dbobrowski i modified my answer to fit your question better, hopes it helps

Comment: @helmus thanks, good advice on that last bit - something I was concerned with as well.

I'll take a look around for other options, at least I now know I should be looking elsewhere and what I want to accomplish is not appropriate to do so with OOTB jQuery datepicker